# How to exclude file when build electron with electron-builder?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

What I want is not exclude unused file, but exclude used file package into `.exe` file

I provide a file like `config.json` for user to edit some custom config, then the application could read the file to do something. So I don't hope this file package into `.exe` file.

How should I config electron-builder to exclude this file?

Answer (score 8):

You can specify what files to package using the configuration, either inside `package.json` or in a separate config file for `electron-builder`.

The `build` section of the `package.json` contains the settings for `electron-builder`. The `files` key then contains information what to include in the package. The following example excludes the file `foo.json`.

```js
{
    "name": "myApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",


    "build": {
        "files": "!foo.json"
    }

}
```

There are many options available, e.g. to exclude several glob patterns or to specify exactly which files to *included*. You can also make all these settings platform-specific. For all options, see the [docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#files).